# How to add navigation to a screen without it showing up in the drawer

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

I have this code in which I setup a drawer navigator

```
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

const MyDrawer = () => {
  return(
    <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Test">
      <Drawer.Screen name="Test" component={Test}/>
      <Drawer.Screen name="Menu" component={Menu}/>
      <Drawer.Screen name="Dish Detail" component={DishDetail} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
}
```

I want to be able to navigate to the `Dish Detail` screen by clicking a Button component in the `Menu` Screen. But I also want to be able to navigate between the `Test` and `Menu` screens using a drawer. So, when I add navigation to the `Dish Detail` screen, it shows up in the drawer which is not good because I need to pass different props to it depending on what button is clicked.

Comment: If you are not going to navigate to Dish Detail from test screen better use a Stack Navigator for Menu and Dish details and add that stack to the drawer, as there is no way to hide item from drawer as of now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hiding-tabbar-in-screens/) have a similar situation, when you want to have a screen that is not shown in the bottom tab bar.

The solution is to create a Stack Navigator where `MyDrawer` is a Screen:

```
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

const MyDrawer = () => {
  return(
    <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Test">
      <Drawer.Screen name="Test" component={Test}/>
      <Drawer.Screen name="Menu" component={Menu}/>
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
}

const AppStack = createStackNavigator();

const MyStack = () => {
  return(
    <AppStack.Navigator initialRouteName="Drawer">
      <AppStack.Screen name="Drawer" component={MyDrawer}/>
      <AppStack.Screen name="Dish Detail" component={DishDetail} />
    </AppStack.Navigator>
  );
}
```